# ¿como hago con javascript para que el browser me descargue el archivo generado?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una app servidor que me devuelve un archivo xls, y desde javascript hago la llamada POST, para que cuando retorne el archivo, ocultar el gif de "cargando..." y que el browser permita descargar el archivo.
Si yo hago $( "#respuestas_form" ).submit(); funciona perfecto, pero no puedo ocultar el gif de "cargando...". Entonces usé lo siguiente pero no me funciona:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $('#respuestas_form').attr('action'),
  data: {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
 'encuesta_id': $( "#encuesta_id" ).val(),
  },
  success: function(result){
    $("#div_cargando").hide();
 $( "#errors" ).html("");
 var contentType = "application/ms-excel";
 var filename = "marcelo.xlsx"
 //var attachment = "attachment";
 //var blob = new Blob([result], { type: contentType, Content-Disposition: attachment });
 return new File([result], filename, {type: contentType, lastModified: Date.now()});
 //window.open(filename);

  }
});
```

¿como debería hacer para que el browser me permita descargar el archivo?

Comment: Pero qué errores te da el código?, y cómo es el script de la url a la que llamas?

Comment: Nno dá ningún error el código pero la respuesta no hace que el browser abra un cuadro de dialogo para abrir o descargar el archivo. Yo veo en la respuesta a esa petición POST y veo el archivo (en formato binario),

Comment: No estoy seguro pero me parece que con ajax no puedes descargar archivos , llama directamente al enlace

Comment: Puedes usar la función `$("elemntoDOM").load("url?parametrosGET",{parametrosPOST});` NOTA: Si utilizas parámetros `GET`, evita utilizar parámetros `POST`. Para más info: [función `load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. Pero me parece que no debo llamar a la función load ya que no necesito llamar a otra url, necesito que el browser interprete esos datos binarios. Una solución que se me ocurrió, es crear un elemento en el DOM y a ese elemento inyectarle los datos binarios el atributos como el contentType, luego forzar un clic en ese elemento. Esta opción funciona, la probé, pero hay algun problema en los datos binarios que el programa encargado de abrirlo no puede, quiza es porque mediante javascript he grabado algun caracter de mas, o no se.